# probability of 2 items being present at adjacent positions in a sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume that I have 3 maple trees, 4 oaks and 5 birch trees in a row and I plant them in random order, each arrangement being equally likely. What is the probability that no 2 birch trees are planted next to each other.

I tried to keep 5 birch trees and then I have 6 places to keep the remaining trees and I have 5 trees remaining. So I thought the number of places to plant the trees will be given by the number of positive integral solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 7$$

which is ${6}\choose{5}$. This multiplied by $7!/3!4!$ should give me the favourable outcomes. This divided by $12!/3!4!5!$ should give me the required probability right? Is my approach wrong because the answer is not matching

Comment: I guess you can forget about oaks and maples and just call them 'other trees'

Comment: Is there any mistake in my method?

Comment: it seems like a mistake, you have 5 birch trees and 7 other trees.  the 5 birch trees could initially be BxBxBxBxB which is 9 trees (then whatever you do it will work, but remembering that you have to choose a gap between birches, not a position), the remaining 3 can go between any birches, or before after them, so that is how many ways can 3 go into 6 slots, with >1 can be in a slot, which is stars and bars again, and gives  $\dbinom{8}{5}$ as in KeyFlex answer - were you wanting  $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 3$

Comment: @Cato i got my mistake. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the five birch trees must be placed amongst the seven previous trees. So, we can think of these trees as $5$ dividers of $8$ slots that the birch trees can go in $\dbinom{8}{5}$ different ways.

There are $\dbinom{12}{5}$ ways to arrange the $12$ trees.

So the probability is $\dfrac{\dbinom{8}{5}}{\dbinom{12}{5}}$